# Creating remote thread is crashing the process

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to inject code in a different process, so far there is some success, I can inject data and method in the target process. I can execute remote thread and will get return value after the completion of thread only if the thread function is without body. eg if I omit MessageBox line from ThreadFunc then it will work, but no std::cout/printf/MessageBox can be there and no windows api calls. so either I return immediately from that function or do some simple math operations.

**compiling code**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define cbNewProc       1600

typedef struct {
    HWND hwnd;
} INJDATA, *PINJDATA;

static const char *err_str(void) {
    static char buf[2048];
    if ( FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(), 0, buf,
            sizeof(buf), NULL))
        return buf;
    return "Unknown error";
}

// entry point in remote process
static LRESULT CALLBACK ThreadFunc(LPVOID param) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "I am inside remote process", "Hiiii", 0);
    return 1;
}

static int inject_code(DWORD pid) {
    cout << "Process found: " << pid << endl;

    HANDLE hp = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
    PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);
    if (!hp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "OpenProcess( %s )\n", err_str());
        return 0;
    }

    int size = sizeof(INJDATA) + cbNewProc;
    BYTE* pDataRemote = (BYTE*) VirtualAllocEx(hp, NULL, size,
    MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (!pDataRemote) {
        fprintf(stderr, "VirtualAllocEx( %s )\n", err_str());
        CloseHandle(hp);
        return 0;
    }

    SIZE_T dwNumBytesXferred;
    BYTE* pNewProcRemote = pDataRemote + sizeof(INJDATA);
    if (!WriteProcessMemory(hp, pNewProcRemote, (void*) &ThreadFunc,
    cbNewProc, &dwNumBytesXferred)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "WriteProcessMemory( %s )\n", err_str());
        VirtualFreeEx(hp, pDataRemote, size, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hp);
        return 0;
    }

    INJDATA DataLocal;
    ZeroMemory(&DataLocal, sizeof(INJDATA));
    if (!WriteProcessMemory(hp, pDataRemote, &DataLocal, sizeof(INJDATA),
            &dwNumBytesXferred)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "WriteProcessMemory( %s )\n", err_str());
        VirtualFreeEx(hp, pDataRemote, size, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hp);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("pDataRemote=%ld\n", pDataRemote);
    printf("pNewProcRemote1=%ld\n", pNewProcRemote);
    printf("pNewProcRemote2=%ld\n", pNewProcRemote + cbNewProc);

    int nSuccess = 0;
    DWORD dwThreadId;
    HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hp, NULL, 0,
            (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) pNewProcRemote, pDataRemote, 0,
            &dwThreadId);
    if (hThread == 0) {
        cout << "CreateRemoteThread failed" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    GetExitCodeThread(hThread, (PDWORD) &nSuccess);
    VirtualFreeEx(hp, pDataRemote, size, MEM_RELEASE);
    cout << "nSuccess=" << nSuccess << ", size=" << size << endl;

    CloseHandle(hp);
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    cout << "Remote Thread" << endl;

    HANDLE h;
    PROCESSENTRY32 p;

    h = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "CreateToolHelp32Snapshot( %s )\n", err_str());
        return 0;
    }

    p.dwSize = sizeof(p);

    if (!Process32First(h, &p)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Process32First( %s )\n", err_str());
        goto out_close;
    }

    do {
        if (strcasecmp(p.szExeFile, "dllexp.exe"))
            continue;
        inject_code(p.th32ProcessID);
    } while (Process32Next(h, &p));

    out_close: CloseHandle(h);
    return 0;
}
```

Usually target process will crash with a page fault or invalid read location error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is doomed to failure. Your code is based on the assumption that the address of `MessageBoxA` in your program will, in the target process, also be the address of `MessageBoxA`. There is no reason for that to be true. Your code is based on the assumption that the target process will contain string literals at the same address as the calling program, and again there is no reason to expect that. There's no reason to expect that the target process has the same runtime as your process, located at the same addresses. And so on.

When injecting by `CreateRemoteThread` there are two common approaches:

1. If you are in control of both processes, then you can arrange for the target process to have a thread function whose address you can obtain, for instance by IPC. In other words you compile the thread function into the target process and it is sitting there waiting for you.
2. The signature of a thread function is compatible with that of `LoadLibrary`. So you pass the address of `LoadLibrary` (in the target process) and pass a parameter that is the address of a null-terminated character array allocated in the target process. That character array contains the path to a DLL which is then loaded into the target process and in turn starts another thread in its `DllMain` which performs whatever work needs to be done.

Examples of both approaches are widely available and will be found with websearch.

Comment: You are saying that dll injection is the only possibility but http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces guy has mentioned one method without dll route, i just cant seem to get it working.

Comment: You aren't adhering to all the caveats listed there

Comment: I believe I have followed steps from 1 - 10 and then changed to "release" build, also MessageBox is in user32 and the author says module user32 is mapped at the same location in both current and remote process. I have pasted the code from the example, if you can take a look. – btw i am using mingw compiler can that make a difference ?

Comment: I see no reason to believe that user32 will be loaded at a stable address. Further, depending on the linker used, `MessageBoxA` may point to a stub rather than the function in user32. You are infringing caveat number 2 from that article.

Comment: right, i violated no 2, when i sent the string via injdata ( string memcpied ), still its failing so maybe as you said the problem is with  api address incorrectly mapped

Comment: I think that the question is over, and I don't understand your edits. If you want to ask a new question, make a new question. I reverted to the question that I answered.

Comment: your last reply is still valid, i am now following a different route, i will start another thread.